# Vlookup if in range R

Tags: r

I have a set of entries (ColumnA), each entry has a valid_from and a valid_to columns associated (ColumnB, ColumnC), where the entries are dates. Entries can be duplicates.

Then I have another Df where I have entries with relevant dates.

```
ColumnA     ColumnB      ColumnC                ColumnD     ColumnE     ColumnF
x           20190101     20190105               x           20190125      €35
y           20190201     20190210               y           20190205      €40
```

I need to return the values of ColumnF only when the date in ColumnE is included in the interval between ColumB and C.

Any ideas?

Comment: `df$ColumnF[df$ColumnB < df$ColumnE & df$ColumnC >df$ColumnE]`

Comment: have you checked the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a dataframe column is `$`. Select the right indexes of your column using `[]`, `AND` function is `&`. Comparisons are made using `>, >=, <, <=, =`.

```
df$ColumnF[df$ColumnB < df$ColumnE & df$ColumnC > df$ColumnE]
```